# Photo field not syncing in SharePoint 2016 using Microsoft Identity Manager

Tags: user-profile-service, mim

I have installed MIM 2016 and run a photo sync in SharePoint 2016, but I am having some problem as some users' photos are not being synced in SharePoint even though they have photos in AD. Other users are getting their photos.

When I check `Metaverse object properties` in MIM of a user whose photo did not import, I see that the property photo contains binary value in. `Example:photo FF D8 FF E0 ...`

How do I check now what is wrong with the SharePoint import in MIM?